# KSH password generator

Tags: password, ksh, random

How to make sure the generated passwords contains all these special characters: `?!/=\`?

Currently I'm using:

```
pwd_usr["$i"]=`cat /dev/urandom|tr -dc "a-zA-Z0-9-_\?\!\=\/\"|fold -w 15|head -n 1`
```

But some of the generated passwords full not contain the special characters I want.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `grep` command to filter the generated passwords for those which contain the special characters:

```
LC_ALL=C </dev/urandom tr -cd '_a-zA-Z0-9-\?\!\=\/' | \
fold -w15 | grep '[\?\!\=\/]' | head -1
```

**NOTES:**

1. I added `LC_ALL=C` because, depending on the system's locale, `tr` will produce the error *Illegal byte sequence* if presented with binary data (as generated by /dev/urandom).
2. Instead of `cat /dev/urandom`, use redirection: `<file command` or `command <file`.